# AWK Column match

Tags: linux

I am trying to find a column match with grep but with no luck
Below is my DataSet

```
A1|B1|C1
A11|B2|C111
A1|B23|C97
```

```
cat file|while IFS="|" read -r A B C
do
  x1=`egrep $A $file`. # here I want A1 should be matched to A1 but I am gettin A1/A11/A1 
done
```

I want to compare A1 of 1st line 1st column to A1 of other line it can be 2nd/30th etc.
So I want to compare column and row to column row.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with either `grep` or `awk`. With `grep` using an extended REGEX (the `-E` option) will allow you to match using a word-boundary `\b` to distinguish between `"A1"` and `"A11"`, e.g.

```sh
grep -E '^A1\b' data
```

With `awk` using the field-separator (`FS`) of `'|'` you simply save the first field (`$1`) from the first record (`FNR==1`) and then match against the first field for all remaining records, e.g.

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR==1{find=$1;print;next} $1==find' data
```

**Example Use/Output**

In both cases above, with your data in the file named `data` the output is:

```
A1|B1|C1
A1|B23|C97
```

It is unclear what you want to do with the remaining comparisons, but if you make that clear, I'm happy to edit and help further. `awk` will be the natural choice if you want to compare or manipulate the other fields in each record. Drop a comment or edit your question to clarify what `"compare column and row to column row"` means.